# Error Variable is Protected

Tags: c++, protected

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;

    void armySkirmish();
    void battleOutcome();

    string commander = "";
    int numberOfHumans = 0;
    int numberOfZombies = 0;

    class ArmyValues
    {
        protected:
            double attackPower;
            double defensePower;
            double healthPoints;
    public:
        void setAttackPower(double a)
        {
            attackPower = a;
        }
        void setDefensePower(double d)
        {
            defensePower = d;
        }
        void setHealthPoints(double h)
        {
            healthPoints = h * (defensePower * .1);
        }
};

class Zombies: public ArmyValues
{

};

class Humans: public ArmyValues
{

};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    cout << "Input Commander's Name: " << endl;
    cin >> commander;

    cout << "Enter Number of Human Warriors: " << endl;
    cin >> numberOfHumans;

    cout << "Enter Number of Zombie Warriors: " << endl;
    cin >> numberOfZombies;

    armySkirmish();
    battleOutcome();
    return 0;
}

void armySkirmish()
{

    cout << "\nThe Humans tense as the sound of the undead shuffle towards them." << endl;
    cout << commander << " shuffles forward with a determined look." << endl;
    cout << "The undead form up into ranks and growl a war chant!" << endl;
    cout << commander <<" shouts, CHARGE!!!" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Warriors from both sides blitz across the field!" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "*The Carnage has begun!*" << endl;
    cout << "*Steal, Sparks, and Flesh flies" << endl;
}



void battleOutcome()
{
    int zombieLives = numberOfZombies;
    int humanLives = numberOfHumans;
    int randomNumber = 0;
    int humanDeath = 0;
    int zombieDeath = 0;
    double newHumanLife = 0;
    double newZombieLife = 0;

    Zombies zombieBattleData;
    Humans humanBattleData;

    srand(time(NULL));

    zombieBattleData.setAttackPower(20.0);
    humanBattleData.setAttackPower(35.0);

    zombieBattleData.setDefensePower(15.0);
    humanBattleData.setDefensePower(20.0);

    zombieBattleData.setHealthPoints(150.0);
    humanBattleData.setHealthPoints(300.0);

    while(zombieLives && humanLives > 0)
    {
        randomNumber = 1+(rand()%10);
        if(randomNumber < 6)
        {
            newHumanLife = humanBattleData.healthPoints - zombieBattleData.attackPower;
            if(newHumanLife <= 0)
            {
                humanLives--;
                humanDeath++;
            }
        }else
        {
            newZombieLife = zombieBattleData.healthPoints - humanBattleData.attackPower;
            if(newZombieLife <= 0)
            {
                zombieLives--;
                zombieDeath++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(zombieLives <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Humans have emerged victorious!" << endl;
        cout << "Human Deaths: " << humanDeath << "Zombie Deaths: " << zombieDeath << endl;
    }else if(humanLives <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Zombies have emerges victorious!" << endl;
        cout << "Human Deaths: " << humanDeath << "Zombie Deaths: " << zombieDeath << endl;
    }
```

I know the code wont run properly as of now. What I was doing was a test run to make sure I was receiving no errors. The two errors I'm getting are:

> ```
> armySimulatorMain.cpp:25:10: error: 'double ArmyValues::healthPoints' is protected 
>
>
> armySimulatorMain.cpp:115:67: error: within this context.
> ```
>
> newHumanLife = humanBattleData.healthPoints - zombieBattleData.attackPower;

This is the case for Attack Power and Health Power however, Defense power is clearing the errors. i don't understand why they are getting flagged. I'm changing the variable through the public function so shouldn't this be allowed?

Also, I'm calling three variables outside of all functions because they are being used by multiple functions. How can I plug those variables somewhere I don't like that they are floating freely above everything?

Thanks guys I can't believe I forgot about getters... Anyway the code runs now much appreciated I'll make sure to remember this time xD

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need all the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not complaining about the line where you set the values; as you say, that uses a public function. But here, you try to read the protected member variables:

```
newHumanLife = humanBattleData.healthPoints - zombieBattleData.attackPower;
```

You only try to read two variables, and those are the ones it complains about.

You'll need a public getter function to read the values.

Comment: ..... and to call those getters rather than directly accessing the members.   A member might be SET with a setter, but that doesn't permit non-member non-friend functions to retrieve the values of protected members.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like:

```
public:
    double gethealthPoints()
    {
       return healthPoints;
    }
```

because `attackPower, defensePower, healthPoints` are all protected, so if you want to access to any of them you need a getter, otherwise you will always receive an protect error